# How to go back to a previous activity in android?

Tags: android

I want to do something simple in an android app.

How to go back to a previous activity?

I have tried pressing the back button on a smartphone, but it returns to display the application menu and exits from application.

What am I missing? What's wrong with this code?

```
    Button qsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    qsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this,
                    "Start", "Start ...", false,
                    false);

            int secondsDelayed = 3;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            HomeActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, secondsDelayed * 1000);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                    HomeActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `finish();` statement from your `run()` method if you want the current activity to stay on the stack so you can return to it when finishing your next activity.

Answer (score 0):

You call finish after opening the second activity. finish() exists your fist activity. So when you exit your second activity you fall back to the opener of your fist activity.